# How to use Basic Routing methods in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have get some documents from Laravel Documentation.But i can't get details clearly from that. There are lot of routing methods and how to use that for my requirements? Commonly most people are using this, but what are the other routing methods?

```
Route::get()
Route::post()
```

How to pass the message or values through this Routing? Using Controller like this is a only way?

```
Route::get('/app', 'AppController@index');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Types of Routing in Laravel**

There are some Routing methods in Laravel, There are

**1. Basic GET Route**

`GET` is the method which is used to retrieve a resource. In this example, we are simply getting the user route requirements then return the message to  him.

```
Route::get('/home', function() { return 'This is Home'; });
```

**2. Basic POST Route**

To make a `POST` request, you can simply use the post(); method, that means when your are submitting a Form using `action="myForm" method="POST"`, then you want to catch the `POST` response using this `POST` route.

```
Route::post('/myForm', function() {return 'Your Form has posted '; });
```

**3. Registering A Route For Multiple Verbs**

Here you can retrieve `GET` request and `POST` requests in one route. `MATCH` will get that request here,

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/home', function() { return 'GET & POST'; });
```

**4. Any HTTP Verb**

Registering A Route Responding To Any HTTP Verb. This will catch all the request from your URL according to the parameters.

```
Route::any('/home', function() {  return 'Hello World'; });
```

---

**Usage of Routing in Laravel**

When your are Using the `Route::`, Here you can manage your controller functions and views as follows,

**1. Simple Message Return**

You can return a simple message which will display in the webpage when user request that URL.

```
Route::get('/home', function(){return 'You Are Requesting Home';});
```

**2. Return a View**

You can return a View which will display in the webpage when user request that URL

```
// show a static view for the home page (app/views/home.blade.php)
Route::get('/home', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});
```

**3. Request a Controller Function**

You can call a function from the Controller when user request that URL

```
// call a index function from HomeController (app/Http/Controllers)
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

**4. Catch a value from URL**

You can catch a value from requested URL then pass that value to a function from Controller. Example : If you call `public/home/1452` then value 1452 will be cached and will pass to the controller

```
// call a show function from HomeController (app/Http/Controllers)
Route::get('/home/{id}', 'HomeController@show');
```

Comment: Thankyou, I am getting much more thing from your single answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get help about routing from [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing).

There are 4 methods ofform data sending that you must know --

1. `Route::get` for `<form method="GET">`
2. `Route::post` for `<form method="POST">`
3. `Route::put` for `<form method="PUT">` -- This one is for updating your database, I recommend you to use [laravelcollective/html](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/html), like this -- `{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT']) !!}`, but in your web browser you can find the method as `POST` only
4. `Route::delete` for `<form method="DELETE">` -- This one is for deleteing a field in your database, I recommend you to use [laravelcollective/html](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/html), like this -- `{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE']) !!}`, but in your web browser you can find the method as `POST` only

There are many much you have to know about Laravel Routing, like CRUD, etc.